# How to convert an Array of objects single JSON Document/Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to convert an array objects to a JSON Document

My array is

```
var images = [{"id1":{"type":"image/png",data:blob}}, {...}, {..}  ...];
```

And I want to convert it into a Json Document containing all the elements of array

ex:

```
var someOtherObject = {
"_id":"12345",
"name":"test",
"_attachments":{images[0],images[1]...}
```

the array size is dynamic, So i can't hardcode them as i did above.

Thanks

Comment: JSON Document? What is that?

Comment: what do you mean by json document?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(obj)`?

Comment: @Teemu Document/Object like we do in Mongo/couchdb

Answer (score 0):

If you `_attachments` is dynamic, it should be an array of objects inside your main object.

```
var images = [{"id1":{"type":"image/png",data:blob}}, {...}, {..}  ...];

var someOtherObject = {
"_id":"12345",
"name":"test",
"_attachments":images
```

Comment: it is not dynamic this is actually pouchdb document, if i put my array it will be stored as single object. whenever i access the document i have to iterate each element of array separately. instead i want to put it as attachments collection so that i can use pouchdb api to fetch individual document.  you can have a look at this  api here. http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html